# How to change the size of these buttons?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jbutton

How to change the size of these buttons?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class xog extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel mainPanel;

     JButton[][] butArray=new JButton[3][3];
     private int counter1=0;
    int size=3;
    int firstrow,firstcol,secondrow,secomdcol;

    public xog(){

        setTitle("XO");
        mainPanel=new JPanel();

        for(int r=0; r<this.size; r++)
            for(int c=0;c<this.size;c++){   
                this.butArray[r][c]=new JButton();
                this.butArray[r][c].setSize(100, 100);
                this.butArray[r][c].addActionListener(this);
                this.mainPanel.add(this.butArray[r][c]);

            }
        validate();

        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        for(int r=0; r<size; r++)
            for(int c=0;c<size;c++){
            if(e.getSource()==butArray[r][c]){
                counter1++;

            if(counter1%2==0){
                butArray[r][c].setText("x");
                this.butArray[r][c].setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            if(counter1%2==1){
                butArray[r][c].setText("o");
                this.butArray[r][c].setBackground(Color.blue);
            }
            }   
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {   
            new xog().setVisible(true); 
        }
        });     
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: `JButton[][] butArray=new JButton[3][3];` Does this mean, as I suspect, that the buttons should be visually arranges in a 3 wide by 3 tall group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `setSize` (and `setBounds`) is pointless, because Swing is using making use of layout managers (in your case `FlowLayout`) which are making decisions about how large and where the components should be laid out.

Second, `setPreferredSize` is a very poor choice.  Why?  The preferred size of the button will be affect by a number things, including the size/amount of the text and the current font metrics and DPI rendering characteristics of the system that the program is been run on.

All these settings can change and you'd be stuck with a program that, basically, looks like crap.

## You could...

Use [`Button#setMargin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin-java.awt.Insets-) which will add the margins to the buttons current preferred size of the button.

[image: Margins]

This approach is useful as it affects the button itself and provides that information to layout managers who might otherwise not be able to provide the padding support themselves

## You could...

Make use of a layout manager which allows you to provide additional sizing hints which are added to the components preferred size, for example, `GridBagLayout`

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
// This will add 50 pixels to the preferred size's width and height
gbc.ipadx = 50;
gbc.ipady = 50;
JButton[][] butArray = new JButton[3][3];
int size = 3;
for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {

        butArray[r][c] = new JButton();
        add(butArray[r][c], gbc);

    }
}
```

[image: GridBagLayout]

`GridBagLayout` is one of the most flexible and complex layouts available and a decision to use should be made based on your over all needs, not just your need to supply padding to components.

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)